# Android hardware debugging

Tags: android, linux, debugging, hardware

I've bought a tablet recently. It's a **SysTrade's Plug 10.1** (Chinese product of local company). It features a reasonable CPU and quite nice GPU, so I thought it would be great to hardware debug my applications. However, this feature seems not to work on my device...

At beginning I lacked the required **vendor id** so after a few phone calls to SysTrade I received one. But that code didn't work. So I've written a small app and got all 2-byte numbers which I copy-pasted to */etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules*. The problem is that **adb** still can't see my device. What's important my **HTC Wildfire** is successfully recognized so rules are written well.

I know none who owns this tablet so I don't have a possibility to check whether all Plugs or only mine are affected. Any ideas would be highly appreciated...

PS. I'm developing on Linux (Ubuntu 12.10).
PS2. When I connect the device to PC it shows that hardware debugging is turned on, but **adb** doesn't see my device.

Comment: Use `lsusb` to find your vendor id of any USB device (without the need to phone the vendor)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to successfully resolve the issue without rooting the device. The only needed action is to manually add an entry for the device vendorid in **~/.android/adb_usb.ini**.

Normally it should be generated based on */etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules* by *android update adb* command but it seems that this application failed. What's important, vendorid must be given in hex number specific format, which is: **0x(2-BYTE HEX)** for example **0x2207**.

Answer (score 1):

Try running adb on root.

If that doesn't work you can still try to root your device(This may void warranty) and use app like adbWifi. I'm using the latter for debugging and it works: I can run my apps on my M-tech aTAB7t.

Comment: adb on root gave the exact same result as for normal user, i'm gonna contact SysTrade and check how are they about rooting the device. In warranty there's no even a line about it.

Comment: I highly recommend the wifi option, the app itself hands every necessary info to adb. The officially supported device brands on usb are a bit limited in my opinion.

Comment: I've just called SysTrade and they confirmed that rooting the device will not lead to losing the warranty. Furthermore, they offered a email confirmation of their statement which I happily accepted. Now waiting for that message and off to start rooting. BTW, do you know a reasonable guide how to root such a device? :)

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure what I did to my device to get it rooted, but you can start according to [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/202229-how-can-i-root-generic-tablet.html). All I remember was I connected the device to usb and used the adb reboot-bootloader command. There's always an app for cheking wether your device is booted or not.